# Python Poetry: Cannot find beta versions of a package

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am trying to use [SQLAlchemy 1.4 beta](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/download.html#beta) with Poetry. It is [released on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/1.4.0b3/).

Poetry does not recognise the beta package in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
SQLAlchemy = "^1.4.0b3"
```

```sh
poetry install
```

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in pyproject.toml. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.

  SolverProblemError

  Because ...  depends on SQLAlchemy (1.4.0b3) which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
```

How can I tell Poetry to fetch the beta versions of the package?

Comment: This should work, as you explicit specified a prerelease version as the minimum supported version. The warning message you see, says that the `poetry.lock` and `pyproject.toml` are out of sync. This happens if you edit the `pyproject.toml` by hand. If you do this, you have to run `poetry lock` first before running any other `poetry` command. So do this first and try `poetry install` again.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to allow prerelease for a package, you should declare it in the `pyproject.toml` as well: `SQLAlchemy = {version = "^1.4.0b3", allow-prereleases = true}`

Comment: `allow-prereleases = true` was exactly what I was looking for. @finswimmer can you promote your comment to an answer and I can mark this question answered.

Comment: @finswimmer Just FYI it appears that versions such as 1.4.0rc0 are allowed even if allow-prereleases is not set but not 1.4.0rc1 (it seems to depend on the rc0 vs rc1). I'm guessing this is a result of rc0 being a valid version specifier for a scheme other than release candidates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your pyproject.toml you need to specify this dependency in a verbose form (more about it can be found [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification#expanded-dependency-specification-syntax)):

```
SQLAlchemy = {version = "^1.4.0b3"}
```

And then set the option `allow-prereleases` to true so your code would look like

```
SQLAlchemy = {version = "^1.4.0b3", allow-prereleases = true}
```

Alternatively you can add this dependency with a corresponding option usin CLI:

```
poetry add SQLAlchemy@^1.4.0b3 --allow-prereleases
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```py
SQLAlchemy = {version = "^1.4.0*", allow-prereleases = true}
```

Comment: With poetry >1.5, adding the start at the end makes it fail with "Could not parse version constraint".